# Type 'UIPageViewController.OptionsKey' (aka 'NSString') has no member 'interPageSpacing'

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I don't know what's the matter with Xcode. I want to create a `UIPageViewController` using the initializer in one of my company project:

```
init(transitionStyle style: UIPageViewController.TransitionStyle,
     navigationOrientation: UIPageViewController.NavigationOrientation, 
     options: [UIPageViewController.OptionsKey : Any]? = nil)
```

But Xcode keeps giving this error message.

This is my code:

```
let vc = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, 
                              navigationOrientation: .vertical, 
                              options: [UIPageViewController.OptionsKey.interPageSpacing: 10])
```

Meanwhile, in new demo project I created just now from the template `Page-based App` (as bellow), it builds without any error.

[image: template]

How to fix/walkaround it?

Comment: My solution is to change the `Swift Language Version` in **Build Setttings** from `4.0` to `5.0` or `4.2`. And note that doing this means you have to migrate to `5.0` or `4.2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax was different in Swift 4. Your current project might be in Swift 4.0. Change its swift version to 4.2 and above. Or use the below code

```
init(transitionStyle style: UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle, 
    navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation, 
    options: [String : Any]? = nil)
```

**Swift 4.0**

```
let vc = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll,
                                      navigationOrientation: .vertical,
                                      options: [UIPageViewControllerOptionInterPageSpacingKey : 10])
```

**Swift 4.2 and above**

```
let vc = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: .scroll, 
                              navigationOrientation: .vertical, 
                              options: [UIPageViewController.OptionsKey.interPageSpacing : 10])
```